# DropDownList OnSelectedIndexChange not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im new at using C# and ASP.NET im trying to create a signup form which i included a `<asp:DropDownList>` im trying to catch if the `OnSelectedIndexChange` is working but i just get nothing no response.

Here's my **signup.aspx**

```
<form id="signupform" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID ="firstname" class="form-control" type="text"  placeholder="First Name" style="width: 168px;" pattern = "[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]{2,20}" required="true"/>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" class="form-control" type="text" value="" placeholder="Middle Name" style="width: 168px;position: relative;margin-top: -50px;margin-left: 192px;" pattern = "[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]{2,20}" required="true"/>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" class="form-control" type="text"  value="" placeholder="Last Name" pattern = "[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]{2,20}" required="true"/>
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="month" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged ="Month_Selected" class="form-control" style="width: 115px;" required>
        <asp:ListItem Value ="" Text="Month" Selected ="true" Disabled ="true"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value ="January" Text ="January"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value ="February" Text ="February"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value ="March" Text ="March"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value ="April" Text ="April"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value ="May" Text ="May"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value ="June" Text ="June"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value ="July" Text ="July"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value ="August" Text ="August"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value ="September" Text ="September"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value ="October" Text ="October"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value ="November" Text ="November"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value ="December" Text ="December"></asp:ListItem>
     </asp:DropDownList>
    //other personal input infos
</form>
```

and here's **signup.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;


public partial class signup : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

   }

   protected void Month_Selected(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

    Response.Write("working");
   }

}
```

please help i don't know what is wrong, I tried to look in other questions but none is working.

**UPDATE 1.**

by submitting the form i can get the values from the `DropDownList` but the OnSelectedIndexChange still not working

and also there is no error in console.

Comment: Try using `ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock` or `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` (if you have ScriptManager control).

Comment: is there any other way to output a javascript alert box? i also tried `Response.write("working")` but i got nothing

Comment: `Response.Write` doesn't show alert box, it writes directly to page. You need to register script in page/ScriptManager to get it work.

Comment: i just tried `Response` to check the `OnSelectedIndexChange`

Comment: Have you checked `month.SelectedValue` in your selected index changed event?

Comment: i tried this still no output sir. `var monthSelected = month.SelectedValue.ToString();
        Response.Write(monthSelected);`

Comment: Is `Response.Write(monthSelected);` returns null or empty string? If the selected value exist it should write directly to browser's page.

Comment: How is you page attributes looks like ? `<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage/Reports.Master"..... 
    AutoEventWireup="true" Async="true" %>` is it having Async attribute ?

Comment: Can you also add value to first item and check

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock()` method as alternative to `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript()`:

```
protected void Month_Selected(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, GetType(), "alert", "alert('working');", true);
}
```

Or if you have `ScriptManager` instance (i.e. `<asp:ScriptManager>`), you can use `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript()` method:

```
protected void Month_Selected(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "alert", "alert('working');", true);
}
```

Or use `Response.Write` to write your `script` tags manually:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(month.SelectedValue))
{
    Response.Write("<script>alert('working');</script>");
}
```

Note that you need server-side form tag (i.e. `<form runat="server">...</form>` to get script executed successfully.

Comment: sir i tried to execute all of your given codes but none is working

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the value or text in a string.
Then output it in the alert as shown below.

```
    protected void Month_Selected(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string wildchild = month.SelectedItem.Text + " - " + month.SelectedItem.Value;
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + wildchild + "');", true);
}
```